# trustworthy p2p solution to accelerate apt-get dist-upgrade

Tags: upgrade, apt, p2p

Do you know any good and working solution for making apt-get dist-ugprade faster?
I remember trying out apt-p2p a while ago but it was not wokring well.
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like using apt-fast, it's not p2p, but it does multiple downloads per file, speeding up the downloads for getting packages. Link showing how to install, http://www.webupd8.org/2010/08/you-can-now-install-apt-fast-from-ppa.html

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tldm217/tahutek.net
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apt-fast
```

when you use it you can use `apt-fast` insted of `apt-get` so once you install it you can do `apt-fast dist-upgrade`